# Behavior of html form onsubmit event in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, html, onsubmit, forms, http-post

I have a simple form which has nothing other than a submit button. All I want to do is prevent submission of the form (I know it doesn't make any sense but this is only for illustration). So I'm making use of the form's `onsubmit` event and this event `returns false`. This does work but this is where the 'incomprehensible behavior' arises.

I can associate the `return false;` statement with the `onsubmit` event of the form either by using inline `JavaScript` or keep it in a different place.

```
<form onsubmit="return false;" id="form1" method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="btnButton" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Now, the aforementioned code works just fine. See => http://jsfiddle.net/MccK5/

I can even modify the above code as follows in order to make the JavaScript separate (unobtrusive).

```
--some html markup initially
<form onsubmit="return falsifier()" id="form1" method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="btnButton" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
    function falsifier() {
    return false;
}
</script>


--other html markup follows
```

Here, the script tag is placed right after form in the `HTML` markup.
This works too. See => http://jsfiddle.net/AfdQ5/

But when I shift the `JavaScript` to an different place (ex: external file), this doesn't seem to work.

By taking a look into the console in inspect element, I noted the error `falsifier is not defined`.

See this here => http://jsfiddle.net/5cR5R/2/

Could someone elaborate on why this is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're encountering a design feature (or flaw) in JSFiddle:

In JSFiddle, the "JavaScript" pane is *not* the direct source code of a referenced JavaScript file, instead JSFiddle wraps that code as below and inserts it into `<head>`. Just go View Source to see what it does:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[ 
    window.onload=function(){
        function falsifier() {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //]]>  
</script>
```

Your `<form>` elements can't find `falsifier` because `falsifier` only exists within the scope of this anonymous function.

Comment: I get the point. Incidentally that's how even ASP.NET MVC's BeginForm's onsubmit behaves (which is what was my actual issue). I didn't check the view source; instead simply wondered what was wrong with my code. :)